# Javascript - typeof not working for dynamic object

Tags: javascript

When none of the following child objects have been created

```
if(typeof this.obj[child1][child2]!=="undefined"){
}
```

The above does not work however this does

```
if(typeof this.obj[child1]!=="undefined"){
}
```

Comment: How about `if(typeof this.obj[child1]!=="undefined" && typeof this.obj[child1][child2]!=="undefined")`?

Comment: Well if in both cases `this.obj[child1]` is `undefined` then `this.obj[child1][child2]` would thrown an error like `cannot access property ... of undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need the `typeof ... 'undefined'` to determine if `this.obj[child1][child2]` is not `undefined`. Instead use:

```
if (this.obj && this.obj[child1] && this.obj[child1][child2]) {}
```

As in:

```
var obj = {};
obj.c1 = {};
alert( obj && obj.c1 && obj.c1.c2 ? 'obj.c1.c2 exists' : 'nope'); 
     //=> "nope"
obj.c1.c2 = 1;
alert( obj && obj.c1 && obj.c1.c2 ? 'obj.c1.c2 exists' : 'nope'); 
     //=> "obj.c1.c2 exists"
```

You could create a function to determine the existence of a certain path in any `Object`:

```
function pathExists(root,path){
  var pathx = path.constructor === Array && path || path.split(/\./)
    , trial
    , pathok = true
  ;

  while (pathx.length && pathok) {
    trial = pathx.shift();
    pathok = (root = root && root[trial] || false, root);
  }
  return pathok;
}
// usage examples
var obj = {c1:1};
pathExists(obj,'c1.c2'); //=> false
pathExists(obj,'c1'); //=> 1
obj.c1 = { c2: {c3: 3} };
pathExists(obj,['c1','c2','c3']); //=> 3
// your case
if ( pathExists(this,[obj,child1,child2]) ) { /*...*/ }
```

Answer (score 3):

this is because the priority of `typeof` is lower than that of `[]` or `.`, so the `[]` is executed first and throws an error:

```
> typeof foo == "undefined"
true
> typeof foo.bar == "undefined"
ReferenceError: foo is not defined
```

To check long chains of nested properties you can use a function like this:

```
function hasKeys(obj, keys) {
    for(var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        if(typeof obj[keys[i]] == "undefined")
            return false;
        obj = obj[keys[i]];
    }
    return true;
}

if(hasKeys(this, ["obj", "child1", "child2"])) ...
```

or better, handle an exception:

```
try {
    val = this.obj['foo']['bar']['baz'];
} catch(err) {
    // deal with undefined val
}
```

Comment: Can I put try in a if/else statement though?

Answer (score 0):

use this for the first case -

```
if(this.obj[child1] && typeof this.obj[child1][child2]!=="undefined"){
}
```

Comment: Maybe he also should check if `this.obj[child1]` is an object.

Comment: @RienNeVaPlus what could `this.obj[child1]` be in that case, where `this.obj[child1][child2]` would fail?

Comment: No that is not required. In case `this.obj[child1]` is not an object and is a literal even then javascript will automatically convert it into an object before checking for `child2` item.

Comment: @RienNeVaPlus has to be `undefined` or `null`

Answer (score -1):

This doesn't work because it will throw a JavaScript error. It will throw this.obj[child1] is undefined. You Should always check if it's defined too.

```
if(this.obj[child1] && typeof this.obj[child1][child2]!=="undefined"){
}
```

**EDIT**

If you want to increase your code readability, you could use a function like this:

```
var test = {child1: {child2: "TEST"}};
alert(is_defined(test, 'child1', 'child2')); // true
alert(is_defined(test, 'child1', 'child2', 'child3')); // false

function is_defined(obj) {
    if (typeof obj === 'undefined') return false;

    for (var i = 1, len = arguments.length; i < len; ++i) {
        if (obj[arguments[i]]) {
            obj = obj[arguments[i]];
        } else if (i == (len - 1) && typeof obj[arguments[i] !== 'undefined']) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Ok in practice there any more children so I was hoping to avoid something as long as this but I guess that is not possible.

Comment: This will not work if `this.obj[child1]` is `null`. `TypeError: Cannot read property '...' of null` will be thrown then.

Comment: Actually this isn't working for me as the first argument is causing the conditional to pass as true, I only want the conditional to pass as true if the the final argument is true.

Comment: @t.niese Exactly! See my answer for solving that problem.

Comment: Same issue the conditional must pass, only if the last child exists.

Comment: Fixed the null issue and added a util function you could use if your variable has a lot of children

Comment: I can't pass a helper function an undefined object.

Comment: @user1209203 You don't pass the final object, you pass the root and then use the parameters to go through your path.

Answer (score -4):

Use undefined instead of "undefined" or try null.

Comment: `undefined` is not a reserved keyword, so testing for `typeof something === "undefined"`  is the save way to do it. And `undefined` and `null` are not the same thing.